# Calling custom functions in Intellij IDEA exception breakpoint conditions

Tags: java, debugging, exception, intellij-idea

For debugging Kotlin/Java projects in IDEA I am using filters such as `!(this instanceof java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)` to ignore certain exceptions.

To make these filters easier to maintain and reuse across installations I tried wrapping them in a function and calling that function in the breakpoint  condition like:

`app.AppKt.isDebugException(this)`

This works for exceptions thrown by my local code but breaks with any exceptions thrown by java.lang and third party libraries with a "Breakpoint Condition Error" due to the condition throwing a ClassNotFound exception.

Is there a way to load my AppKt class into IDEA so that the debugging tools will be able to invoke my isDebugException function from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your AppKt is not visible from the bootstrap classloader or the third-party libs classloader. No easy solution for now, please follow discussions in [IDEA-12111](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12111) and related issues.